# Python ValueError (ambiguous truth value) when selecting rows from a data frame using a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a python data frame indexed by ID where each ID occurs more than once. I want to group my data by ID, check each ID for whether it has more than one "source", and then filter my original data to only include rows with IDs that had only one source.

I thought I could do it like this, where the first line gets a list of the IDs to filter by, and the second line does the filtering:

```
df_onesourceids=df.reset_index().groupby('ID').apply(lambda d: d.my_source.nunique()).where(lambda x : x==1).dropna()
df=df.loc[df_onesourceids.index.tolist()]
```

This works interactively, but when I run in our build system, I get an error (on the second line, the first line is fine and produces a series where the index is the ID and the value is 1.0) from pytest (`/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py`) that:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

I've tried lots of workarounds, including the isin function or converting my list to a data frame. I keep getting this error. How can I do this?

Comment: How about some data and expected output as text edited into your question? That's the best way to get _working_ answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(level='ID')['my_source'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```

Or slowier solution with [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby(level='ID').filter(lambda d: d.my_source.nunique() == 1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_source':list('abcccc'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,0,0,0],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]}, index=list('aaabbb'))
df.index.name = 'ID'
print (df)
    B  C  D  E my_source
ID                      
a   4  7  1  5         a
a   5  8  3  3         b
a   4  9  5  6         c
b   0  4  7  9         c
b   0  2  1  2         c
b   0  3  0  4         c

df1 = df.groupby(level='ID').filter(lambda d: d.my_source.nunique() == 1)

df1 = df[df.groupby(level='ID')['my_source'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```

---

```
print (df1)
    B  C  D  E my_source
ID                      
b   0  4  7  9         c
b   0  2  1  2         c
b   0  3  0  4         c
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[df.groupby('ID')['my_source'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```

Comment: Not sure how performant it is, but `df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'my_source']).drop_duplicates('ID', keep=False)` is another option

Comment: I test it and it return something else with `df = pd.DataFrame({'my_source':list('abcccc'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,0,0,0],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'ID':list('aaabbb')})`, can you check it?

Comment: Thank you! The first of your solutions (jezrael) didn't work but the second one did and doesn't slow down my code too much. I'm still curious why my solution isn't ok?

Comment: @Callie so the `filter(lambda d:...` gives you the result you're expecting and not the first option in the answer or the idea I threw out there in my comment? (both the options in this answer give effectively the same result minus the index being moved to a column...)

Comment: I spoke too soon. Jezrael's second solution worked interactively but I get the same ValueError from pytest...why. :(

Comment: Jon, I'll try yours now :)

Comment: @Callie - what does it mean first solution does not work? Some error?

Comment: `ValueError` error obviously means you select some columns which does not exist. Maybe some whitespaces should be problem. What is `print (df.reset_index().columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @Callie the logic is slightly different than the other answers. You'll get only one row for an ID and source value rather than multiple rows where it's the only source but multiple occurrences of the same source for that ID.

Comment: @JonClements, I get a KeyError on your solution. On the first solution from Jezrael, I get the error: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided.

Comment: Yes, is possible use `df[df.groupby('ID')['my_source'].transform('nunique') == 1]` ?

Comment: @jezrael, but if whitespaces were the problem I would expect the code to not work interactively. But if I run it myself it works fine. it's only pytest that fails.

Comment: @JonClements I need to keep all the rows for IDs with one source, because I have other information in the other columns. Jezrael, no, that doesn't work, I'd have to include a reset_index() before grouping by ID and then I get the Unalignable boolean error.

Comment: @Callie you're going to have to update your question to include how you're using pytest and a representative DataFrame... it's possibly a wild goose chase otherwise...

Comment: Yes, I think I get it `df= df[df.reset_index().groupby('ID')['my_source'].transform('nunique').values == 1]`

Comment: @Callie - I edit both answers, I think you need `df.groupby(level='ID')`. Please check it.

Comment: Ah, @jezrael that way works if I reset the index twice! Like this: df=df.reset_index()[df.reset_index().groupby...etc

Comment: @JonClements I think you're probably right. Now both of Jezrael's solutions work interactively, but I get the same old error from pytest.

Comment: @jezrael yes, even with the groupby simplification for indexing (nice!) both work interactively but fail pytest. Same as my original code.

Comment: @Callie - I add new solution with reset_index(), can you check it?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry not to get back to this sooner. Nope, still same problem. I talked with someone at my company who thinks it's a corner case test - maybe when the data set is too small or an ID or a source is missing. I'm working on getting more error feedback to try to investigate that.

Comment: Are data confidental?